# Output Filter for CSV files in AWS Batch Transform

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-processing, amazon-sagemaker

I have been trying to do a batch transform job and I have been getting some issues when joining the input and output into a single file (Input/Output filtering and data joins), but first allow me to provide some context:

1. The model used is XGBoost with output multi:softprob, let's say with N classes.
2. The input and output types are "text/csv", split and assembled with option "Line" respectively.

First, I filter the input data like this, extracting the first 2 items of the csv row.
Input filter:
$[2:]

Then I select that I want to merge the input and output data.

Now, assume that I have N = 20 classes.

I could use an output filter like this, to get the 2 results filtered of the input and the last
20 of the output.

$[0,1,-20,-19,-18,...,-3,-2,-1]

Unfortunately this previous filter expression is longer than 63 characters, and therefore it isn't allowed.

Then I tried using slicing, based on jsonPath and Batch Transform documentation, like this:

$[-20:2]

But, apparently an "Internal server error" occurs when I do this. Nothing is shown in the logs, other than that.

Yes, that's literally the error shown in the logs of the job, like this:

s3://bucket/file1.csv: Internal Server Error

When I try a smaller filter, like $[0,1,-20,-1], it works fine, meaning that the model works great and that every other configuration is correct. But of course what I actually want to obtain are ALL the probabilities for the 20 (N) classes.

**Any suggestion for the output filter in a way that works for N classes and with csv files?**

Thank you in advance.